# How to clean the blade of a handheld pencil sharpener

Tags: cleaning

I have a small handheld pencil sharpener and I detached the blade. I would like to know how to clean/sterilize it without the use of any kind of alcohol.

Comment: Must admit, first time I hear about sterilizing a sharpener. Anyway, this isn't meant to be sterilized. Just throw the pencil shavings to the trash, and to make the sharpener clean you can even use a paper or wet wipe.

Comment: What is the context in which this requires sterilization?  Is it a medical environment?

Comment: @Stan maybe by default, but many brands offer alcohol free version e.g. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAsXX.jpg).

Comment: It sounds like you may be wanting to use the blade for more than sharpening pencils. If this is the case, I would suggest purchasing a blade that is more fit for purpose. If this is for some kind of self-harm, not making assumptions just providing advice based on context provided, I would suggest speaking to someone as there are several medical reasons to not indulge in this.

Answer (score 0):

Sterilization without alcohol is a two-step process.

1. To clean the blade, wash it in hot water with soap or detergent. Rinse with clean water three times.
2. Use an autoclave to sterilize the blade. Autoclaves use saturated steam under pressure of approximately 15 pounds per square inch to achieve a chamber temperature of at least 250°F (121°C) for a prescribed time—usually 30–60 minutes.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **hydrogen peroxide** to sterilize without using alcohol.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide) states

> It is used as an oxidizer, bleaching agent, and antiseptic, usually as a dilute solution (3%–6% by weight) in water for consumer use, and in higher concentrations for industrial use.

Dilutions of up to 12% are widely available "over the counter".

Flush the blade and utensils throughly after use.
Wear protective gloves and glasses.

Comment: The Wikipedia source documents for the article reference you cite also stipulates: Use of liquid chemical sterilants is a reliable method of sterilization only if cleaning precedes treatment, which eliminates organic and inorganic material, and if the proper guidelines for concentration, contact time, temperature, and pH are followed.